# How to implement a singleton

Tags: go, singleton, instance

I want to implement a singleton with Go. The difference between normal singleton is the instance is singleton with different key in map struct. Something like this code. I am not sure is there any data race with the demo code.

```
var instanceLock sync.Mutex
var instances map[string]string

func getDemoInstance(key string) string {
    if value, ok := instances[key]; ok {
        return value
    }
    instanceLock.Lock()
    defer instanceLock.Unlock()
    if value, ok := instances[key]; ok {
        return value
    } else {
        instances[key] = key + key
        return key + key
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is data race, you can confirm by running it with `go run -race main.go`. If one goroutine locks and modifies the map, another goroutine may be reading it before the lock.

You may use [`sync.RWMutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#RWMutex) to read-lock when just reading it (multiple readers are allowed without blocking each other).

For example:

```
var (
    instancesMU sync.RWMutex
    instances   = map[string]string{}
)

func getDemoInstance(key string) string {
    instancesMU.RLock()
    if value, ok := instances[key]; ok {
        instancesMU.RUnlock()
        return value
    }

    instancesMU.RUnlock()

    instancesMU.Lock()
    defer instancesMU.Unlock()
    if value, ok := instances[key]; ok {
        return value
    }
    value := key + key
    instances[key] = value
    return value
}
```

Comment: use sync.RWMutex for each get operation will add additional performance cost，I just need to guarantee that at most one instance will be created per map key. any better solution？thanks

Comment: @xiaoxu Yes, that's right. And if you don't use synchronization, your app will become unpredictable. A data race is undefined behavior. There will be no guarantee your app will work correctly. You choose: do you want an app that works correctly slightly slower, or a "faster", incorrect app that might explode at any time.

Comment: is there another better solution to guarantee that at most one instance will be created per map key.

Comment: @xiaoxu If you want it to access concurrently from multiple goroutines, synchronization is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this as well: [sync.Map](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map)

> Map is like a Go map[interface{}]interface{} but is safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines without additional locking or coordination. Loads, stores, and deletes run in amortized constant time.
>
> The Map type is optimized for two common use cases: (1) when the entry for a given key is only ever written once but read many times, as in caches that only grow, or (2) when multiple goroutines read, write, and overwrite entries for disjoint sets of keys.
>
> In these two cases, use of a Map may significantly reduce lock contention compared to a Go map paired with a separate Mutex or RWMutex.

*Note*: In the third paragraph it mentions why using `sync.Map` is beneficial rather than using Go Map simply paired up with `sync.RWMutex`.

So this perfectly fits your case, I guess?

Comment: With just a sync.Map there is no guarantee that at most one instance will be created per map key, which may or may not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Little late to answer, anyways this should help: https://github.com/ashwinshirva/api/tree/master/dp/singleton

This shows two ways to implement singleton:

1. Using the `sync.Mutex`
2. Using `sync.Once`